# Cannot "npm install -g truffle-expect truffle-config web3"?

Tags: truffle, installation

I'm trying to setup development environment of truffle but I got the following error when running `npm install -g truffle-expect truffle-config web3` on Windows 10 enterprise N on Azure.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> npm install -g truffle-expect truffle-config web3

> web3@1.0.0-beta.4 postinstall C:\Users\wanxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3
> lerna bootstrap

'lerna' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\wanxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- truffle-config@1.0.1
`-- truffle-expect@0.0.3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall" "-g" "truffle-expect" "truffle-config" "web3"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! web3@1.0.0-beta.4 postinstall: `lerna bootstrap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the web3@1.0.0-beta.4 postinstall script 'lerna bootstrap'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the web3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     lerna bootstrap
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs web3
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls web3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

How to resolve the issue? I can install everything on Windows 10 professional on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply run `npm install -g truffle` to install truffle,, with **TestRPC** as your Ethereum client, you can install TestRPC using the command `npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc`

It worked for me this way

Comment: I did run `npm install -g truffle` before `npm install -g truffle-expect truffle-config web3`. I followed an instruction which needs to do both these steps. The `truffle init` cannot run right now (popup a js message box) so I thought it's caused by the failed installation.

Comment: Did you install windows build tools? if not try `npm install -g –production windows-build-tools`,, and can you copy/ past the message that you get when you run `truffle init`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error message now. Now `truffle init` finished without any error.

Answer (score 2):

A recent beta.6 change to the postinstall script path for lerna fails on Windows.  Until it's fixed you can `npm install lerna` then `npm install web3@1.0.0-beta.5`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of an issue with this a few days ago when updating truffle. I used [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) instead and didn't have any issues. npm has been really finicky lately for me...

the command with yarn would be:

`yarn global add truffle`